# C# WinForms Traffic Lights cannot be drawn everywhere in my window

Tags: c#, positioning

I made a program which can draw traffic lights. I put one traffic light at the upper left corner and the other traffic light approximately in the middle of the window. But it seems that there is a rectangular field in my program. Only there traffic lights can be drawn. This field begins at the upper left corner and goes to the center of the window. The result is that one traffic light can be seen but the other traffic light is cut at the end of this field. I don't know why

My Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer timer;

    private TrafficLight[] lights;
    private Panel[] light_panels;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new Timer();

        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;

        timer.Interval = 2000;
        timer.Enabled = true;

        timer.Start();

        lights = new TrafficLight[]
        {
            new TrafficLight(10, 10, 75, 150, 0),
            new TrafficLight(50, 50, 75, 150, 2)
        };

        light_panels = new Panel[]
        {
            new Panel(),
            new Panel()
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < light_panels.Length; ++i)
        {
            light_panels[i].Width = lights[i].Width;
            light_panels[i].Height = lights[i].Height;
            light_panels[i].Location = new Point(lights[i].X, lights[i].Y);
            Controls.Add(light_panels[i]);
            light_panels[i].Paint += PLight_Paint;
        }

        CenterToScreen();
    }

    private void PLight_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Panel p = sender as Panel;

        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < light_panels.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(light_panels[i], p))
            {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Gray), lights[index].X, lights[index].Y, lights[index].Width, lights[index].Height);

        switch (lights[index].State)
        {
            case 0:
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), lights[index].X + 10, lights[index].Y + 5, lights[index].Width - 30, lights[index].Height / 3 - 10);
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), lights[index].X + 10, lights[index].Y + lights[index].Height / 3, lights[index].Width - 30, lights[index].Height / 3 - 10);
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), lights[index].X + 10, lights[index].Y + lights[index].Height / 3 * 2 - 5, lights[index].Width - 30, lights[index].Height / 3 - 10);
                break;
            case 1:
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), lights[index].X + 10, lights[index].Y + 5, lights[index].Width - 30, lights[index].Height / 3 - 10);
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Orange), lights[index].X + 10, lights[index].Y + lights[index].Height / 3, lights[index].Width - 30, lights[index].Height / 3 - 10);
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), lights[index].X + 10, lights[index].Y + lights[index].Height / 3 * 2 - 5, lights[index].Width - 30, lights[index].Height / 3 - 10);
                break;
            case 2:
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), lights[index].X + 10, lights[index].Y + 5, lights[index].Width - 30, lights[index].Height / 3 - 10);
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), lights[index].X + 10, lights[index].Y + lights[index].Height / 3, lights[index].Width - 30, lights[index].Height / 3 - 10);
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), lights[index].X + 10, lights[index].Y + lights[index].Height / 3 * 2 - 5, lights[index].Width - 30, lights[index].Height / 3 - 10);
                break;
            case 3:
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), lights[index].X + 10, lights[index].Y + 5, lights[index].Width - 30, lights[index].Height / 3 - 10);
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Orange), lights[index].X + 10, lights[index].Y + lights[index].Height / 3, lights[index].Width - 30, lights[index].Height / 3 - 10);
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), lights[index].X + 10, lights[index].Y + lights[index].Height / 3 * 2 - 5, lights[index].Width - 30, lights[index].Height / 3 - 10);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lights.Length; ++i)
        {
            lights[i].Switch();
            light_panels[i].Invalidate();
            light_panels[i].Update();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

[image]

What can I do to solve this problem?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Check the size of the panel you're drawing on, it's probably smaller than the window

Comment: There are two panels in my program each contains a traffic light. The panels are directly on the window

Comment: Shouldn't the drawing in each panel start at (0,0)?

Comment: The arguments to the TrafficLight constructor are pretty mysterious, it certainly doesn't look like a 75 * 150 image.  Very hard to see how anybody could get a repro from this snippet.  Consider setting the BackColor property so it is more obvious how large the panel actually is.  Also rather important to avoid Panel to do this, it was optimized to be a container control and has unusual painting behavior.  You prefer PictureBox here, ideally your own control class derived from Control.

Comment: @Hans:  _Panel.. has unusual painting behavior._ Never noticed anything like that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @TAW - It has its ResizeRedraw property set to *false*.  That is fine for a container control, only repainting the part of the control that is revealed by a resize is good enough.  But produces interesting psychedelic effects when its Paint event handler does painting based on the control size.  Usually looks like a smear.